# ¿Cómo implementar el LocalStorage en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Quiero implementar el LocalStorage en este componente pero estoy atorado ¿Alguien me podria ayudar a implementarlo?

Lo que busco es guardar la información del usuario para que al momento que vuelva a iniciar la aplicación no se borre y logre mantener los cambios.

Ya intente con los tutoriales de las Webs que encontre en Google pero realmente no fueron de mucha ayuda para mi, les comparto mi código a continuación:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Button, Dialog, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Email, Lock } from '@material-ui/icons';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import bio from '../../assets/react.jpeg';
import axios from "axios";

let authToken ='';

class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            badLogin: '',
            dialogOpen:false,
            dialogPass:false,
            forgottenPwdEmail:'',
            checkEmail: '',
            emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'},
            passwordClicked:{backgroundColor: 'white',color: 'black'}
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        if(event.currentTarget.className.includes("email")){
            this.setState({emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'blue',color:'white'}});
        } else if(event.currentTarget.className.includes("password")) {
            this.setState({passwordClicked:{backgroundColor:'blue',color:'white'}});
        } else {
            this.setState({dialogOpen:true})
        }
    }

    handleBlur(event) {
        if(event.currentTarget.name === 'email'){
            this.setState({emailClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'}});
        } else if (event.currentTarget.name === 'password') {
            this.setState({passwordClicked:{backgroundColor:'white',color:'black'}});
        }
    }

    handleClose(){
        this.setState({dialogOpen:false})
        this.setState({dialogPass:false})
    }

    attemptLogIn(){
        axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://reqres.in/api/'
        axios.post('login', JSON.stringify({"email":this.state.email,"password":this.state.password}),
        {headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}})
        .then(response =>{
            console.log(response)
            return response.data
        })
        .then(data => {
            this.props.LogIn(data)
            this.props.history.push('/mainview');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.setState({dialogPass:true})
        });
    }

    render() {
        let display_message;
        if (this.state.badLogin){
            display_message = <p style={{marginBottom:0}}>{this.state.badLogin}</p>
        }
        document.body.style = 'background: #FFFFFF';
        return(
            <div align="center" className='centered-elements'>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
                <img className="img-logo" src={bio} alt="biologo" style={{margin:'auto',height:337,width:600}} />
                <Typography><h1 className="titulo-login">¡Bienvenido al Blog de React!</h1></Typography>
                <form onSubmit={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}>
                <table className='form-table' style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr className="login-table-tr tr-first" align="center">
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-icon td-first" style={this.state.emailClicked}><Email style={{fontSize: 40}}></Email></td>
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-input td-second">
                            <TextField type="email" name="email" label="Correo electrónico"
                              className="disable-selection email" variant="outlined"
                              onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={this.handleClick} onBlur={this.handleBlur}/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr className="login-table-tr tr-second" align="center">
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-icon td-first" style={this.state.passwordClicked}><Lock style={{fontSize: 40}}></Lock></td>
                          <td className="login-table-td login-table-td-input td-second">
                            <TextField type="password" name="password" label="Contraseña"
                              className="disable-selection password" variant="outlined"
                              onChange={this.handleChange} onClick={this.handleClick} onBlur={this.handleBlur}/>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <Typography>
                    <p style={{color: 'black', width:'440px', textAlign:'right', fontSize:"0.8em"}}>
                      <b onClick={this.handleClick} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</b>
                    </p>
                    <p style={{color: '#ef5350'}}>{display_message}</p>
                    <p style={{color: 'black', width:'440px', textAlign:'right', fontSize:"0.8em"}}>
                    ¿Eres nuevo en el Blog de React? <br/>    
                        <Link to={`/signup`}>
                        ¡¡Registrate!!
                        </Link>
                        
                    </p>
                    </Typography>
                    <div style={{width: '440px'}}>
                      <Button align="right" className="login-button" onClick={() => this.attemptLogIn()} type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</Button>
                    </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                </form>

                <Dialog
                    open={this.state.dialogOpen}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
                >

                    <div style={{width:'500px',height:'320px'}}>
                    <div className="outer" style={{width:'500px',height:'270px'}}>
                        <div className="middle">
                        <div className="inner">
                            <p>    </p>
                            <h2 style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight:'500'}}>Recuperar contraseña</h2>
                            <p style={{padding: '0 10% 0 10%'}}>Introduzca la dirección de correo electrónico asociados con su cuenta de Bio-alchemist</p>
                            <input type="email" name="forgottenPwdEmail" className="disable-selection" onChange={this.handleChange} style={{marginLeft: '40px', width:'80%', border:'solid 1px #4c4c4c', borderRadius:'3px'}}></input>
                            <p style={{padding: '0 10% 0 10%', color: '#ac5fd3'}}>{this.state.checkEmail}</p>
                            <div className="holder">
                            <Button id="pop-up-button" className="login-button" onClick={(e) => this.recoverPassword(e)}>Recuperar contraseña</Button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Dialog>

                <Dialog
                    open={this.state.dialogPass}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                    aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
                >

                    <div style={{width:'500px',height:'170px'}}>
                    <div className="outer" style={{width:'500px',height:'120px'}}>
                        <div className="middle">
                        <div className="inner">
                            <p>    </p>
                            <Typography><h2 style={{textAlign: 'center', fontWeight:'500'}}>Error, tus datos son incorrectos</h2>
                            <p style={{padding: '0 10% 0 10%'}}>Favor de introducir una direccion de correo electronico y un password validos</p></Typography>
                            <div className="holder" align="center" >
                            <Button id="pop-up-button" className="login-button" onClick={this.handleClose}>Cerrar</Button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Soy nuevo en React, por lo que me van surgiendo muchas dudas conforme voy avanzando y en ocasiones me atoro, por lo que les agradezco mucho cualquier comentario o respuesta de todos ustedes!

Comment: Hola Erik, y donde quieres hacerlo? puedes hacerlo desde `window.localStorage.setItem` y `window.localStorage.getItem`

Comment: Con setItem German! y lo que quiero es almacenar los datos que le pido al API, el mail y el password

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localStorage` es una variable global, los metodos principales es `setItem(key, value)` y `getItem(key)`

En tu codigo si lo que quieres es guardar todo el objeto state en local storage, tienes que hacerle `JSON.stringify(object)`

Aquí la documentación de localStorage, recuerda que no es necesario usar el `window.`

[localStorage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Quedaría algo asi: `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.state))`

O si quieres has un nuevo objeto para no guardar los datos innecesarios

Y para obtener luego el usuario es muy facil: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))`