# Manejar estado con contect API y useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy perdiendo los datos de la aplicacion, les explico como esta estructurada la aplicacion.Primero aclarar que no estoy usando `Redux` ni pretendo incorporarlo. EL estado lo estoy manejando a travez de **context** y **useReducer**.Todo el flujo para manejar el estado y acceder al estado me funciona bien. El problema en todo esto es que en el **reducer.js** mi estado inicial es este:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  loading: true,
  books: [],
  recents: [],
  error: null,
};
```

Como se ve el arreglo **books** inicialmente es un arreglo vacio, cuando se carga mi primera ruta **/** , en el `useEffect` se llama al API y a este arreglo se le asignan valores, cuando paso a otra ruta, por ejemplo **/about** accedo al arreglo y los datos estan. El problema comienza cuando en esa ruta **/about**  refresco el navegador**(tocando f5 )** , se hace el re-render y pierdo los datos del array.

Mi pregunta es:

> Como puedo la 1ra vez que traigo los datos del API guardarlo y no perderlos mas?

Si necesitan ver codigo de alguna parte de la logica pidanmelo , no puse todos los ficheros implicados por que son bastantes

Comment: Una forma es usando [localStorage](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266240/como-implementar-el-localstorage-en-react)

Comment: Pero imagina que el arreglo tenga , 10000 elementos, no creo que sea el local storage, la mejor opcion

Comment: Si son tantos registros lo mejor no seria hacer una llamada a la api para obtenerlos?

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente siempre que refresques tus datos se perderan, cada que refresques debes hacer la peticion nuevamente, esto no ocurre siempre ya que tu aplicacion es SPA, no recarga pero si tu lo haces manualmente debes hacer la peticion de nuevo, debes iniciar el estado en loading:false, y pones un if en el useEffect que si loading===false haga la peticion y cuando te trae los datos pones loading=true para que no tengas un bucle infinito
Ejemplo

```
      export const STATUS_LOADING = "LOADING";
        export const STATUS_NOT_LOADED = "NOT_LOADED";
        export const STATUS_LOADED = "LOADED";
    
            let initialState= {
        statusBooks: {
               status: STATUS_NOT_LOADED,
                books: [],
              }
            };
              useEffect(() => {
                if (statusBooks.status === STATUS_NOT_LOADED) {
     setstatusBooks({ ...statusBooks, status: STATUS_LOADING });
                  client()
                    .get(`audit/analyze/allStatus`, {})
                    .then(({ data }) => {
                      if (data) {
                        setstatusBooks({ ...statusBooks, books: data, status: STATUS_LOADED });
                      }
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                      if (e.request.status === 401) {
                        logout();
                      } else if (e.request.status === 422) {
                        setErrors({ error: e.response.data, status: true });
                      } else if (e.request.status === 403) {
                        history.push("../../app/unauthorized");
                      } else {
                        alertError("Error al buscar los libros");
                      }
                    });
                }
              }, []);
```