En un proyecto de React: Gestor de tareas. Quiero que las tareas queden almacenadas luego de cerrar y abrir la app
En el siguiente proyecto: gestor de tareas hecho en React quiero hacer que las tareas queden guardadas o almacenadas una vez que cierre el navegador para que cuando vuelva a abrirlo, las tareas pendientes estén escritas. El tema sucede que cuando hago npm start nuevamente y abro en un puerto diferente las tareas no se guardan. Me ayudado con chatgpt pero no he podido solucionarlo. Desde ya gracias ! les dejo el codigo:
App.js:
import LogoApp from './imagenes/logo-tareas.png';
import './App.css';
import ListaDeTareas from './componentes/ListaDeTareas';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="aplicacion-tareas">
      <div className="logo-contenedor">
        <img
        src={LogoApp} 
        className='logo'
        alt='Logo de la aplicacion'/>
      </div>
      <div className='tareas-lista-principal'>
        <h1>Mis Tareas</h1>
        <ListaDeTareas/>
     
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;




fijate si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/266422/81450

Gracias, acabo de leer la documentación que me enviaste pero al parecer estoy aplicando todo lo que ahí dice... no encuentro el error aun de porque cuando hago npm start nuevamente las tareas no quedan guardadas...

hmm es porque cambia el origin al cambiar el puerto, ahí tal vez lo que te sirva es una cookie que se maneja por domain. la definición de origin es la misma q para cors: protocolo(schema)+dominio(hostname)+puerto  si cambia algo el origin es considerado diferente. en tanto que las cookies pueden ser por dominio o path

Lo mirare Malbarez...Gracias...
